# Full Calender Event array with MVC Model

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am using http://fullcalendar.io/ and I am very noob when it comes to javascript and jquery.

I know that I can add events to calender like this:

```
events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1),
            backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
            borderColor: "#f56954" //red
         },
         {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
            allDay: false,
            backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
            borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
        }
        ]
```

My question is how can I add events with loop using my IEnumarable model.

Comment: I think you just miss `Array.prototype.push()`, a method you'll be able to use on `events` to push a newly created JSON object. Create a new object in your loop then push it into `events` and you're done.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: I don't know about IEnumerable models but I'll post an answer with a simple javascript loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my example, 'Check' is the name of my Model. The if-else statement is used to determine when a comma must be typed - as the last event must not have a comma after it.

You may know that the `@` symbol defines the beginning of C# syntax. However, using `@:` indicates that this line should be treated as a content block.

So as you can see, I have used `@` to begin the `foreach` loop and then anything inside that loop which must JavaScript syntax, has `@:` before it - even the brackets.

The `lastItem` variable defines the last item of the `IEnumerable`. To define a variable in your Razor view you have to use

```
@{(declare variable here)}
```

The if statement will then check to see whether the current item is the last one or not - if it is, then no comma is added to the end.

You'll simply be able to copy my example and edit the properties to your own.

```
events: [
            @{Check lastItem = Model.Last(); }
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                    @:{
                            @: title: ('@item.Name.ToString()'),
                            @: start: ('@item.DateScheduledFor.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss")'),
                            @: description: 'NTO: @item.NTO'
                    @:}

                    if (item != lastItem) {
                        @:,
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @:
                    }
                }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add objects to an array from a loop using `Array.prototype.push()`:

```
var myEvents = [
  { title: "Meeting", date: new Date('01/01/2015') },
  { title: "Lunch", date: new Date('01/05/2015') }
];
myEvents.forEach(function(baseEvent) {
  events.push({ title : baseEvent.title, start: baseEvent.date, allDay: false, backgroundColor: "#f56954" });
});
```